# Upgrade not working for 15.10

Tags: upgrade

I just tried to update my system to the 15.10 system.  I restarted my computer and it still says I am running the 14.04 version.  Am I missing a step after download?

Comment: Sure it's the only Linux-based OS installed? Please edit your question and post the output of `lsb_release -a`. Also run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling Ubuntu 15.10 with a live USB. Make sure to back up your important data.

The cause may be due to apps that only work w/ 14.04, or it may be because you didn't update to 14.10 first and because of that some things were not added in the process of upgrading since some important files were not in the system. The upgrader probably assumed you had those files. Another reson could be that your system is encrypted and it couldn't even add files to the system.